# JWPlayer Android SDK import not working

Tags: android, maven, gradle, sdk, jwplayer

Our company just got a JWPlayer SDK license to use in our Android app.

I tried followed both the maven and local gradle import instructions in the getting started documentation.

If I follow the gradle import instructions, the gradle sync works. But then, when I try to import or use any of the packages, they are not found.

Android Studio seems to be on board with the import statement until this point:

```
import com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.
```

But then if I start adding the individual classes, none of them are recognized:

```
import com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.JWPlayerView;
import com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.events.listeners.AdvertisingEvents;
import com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.events.listeners.VideoPlayerEvents;
import com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.media.adaptive.QualityLevel;
import com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.media.source.SingleSource;
```

And using these in the activity does not work, get the usual "Cannot resolve symbol 'JWPlayerView' " error, for example.

Note,  this does not work either: 
    import com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.*;

If I follow the maven import instructions instead, gradle sync does not work and I get "Failed to resolve: com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayerandroidsdk:+"

There is nothing in their Android SDK FAQ about this beyond "contact support", which I have done. (Nearly a week ago, with no reply).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Attention @Ethan-JWPlayer

Comment: Can you try Build/clean?  Also please post your project & app build.gradle and settings.gradle files.

Answer (score 2):

For the Maven package:

```
com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayerandroidsdk:+
```

should instead be:

```
com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-android-sdk:+
```

Comment: what is the repo ? It doesn't seem to be either on mavencentral or jcentral